# Remove View from SuperView with delay: Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am trying to remove a view form the **superView** with a delay. I have the objective-c code for the same but an not able to implement it in Swift.

Code Snippet:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview) withObject:nil afterDelay:6.5];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can dispatch a closure to run after some delay and remove self from superview in the callback:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 6.5) {
    self.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

If you really want to use `performSelector` approach, here it is:

```
self.perform(#selector(self.removeFromSuperview), with: nil, afterDelay: 6.5)
```

Comment: True, but I was hoping to utilise this method: self.perform(aSelector: Selector, with: Any, afterDelay: TimeInterval)

Comment: @SupratikMajumdar Don't translate Objective-C literally. Try to understand and get used to how Swift handle those things.

Comment: @SupratikMajumdar You can use `performSelector` as well (see the updated anwer), but you shouldn't ;) Selectors are kind of objective-с vestiges

Comment: Just a brief note to remember that the `afterDelay` refers to the **minimum** delay, just incase you run into any weird behaviour :)

Comment: Can anyone please tell how to interrupt/stop this delay before the timer gets  finished? (Only for asyncAfter method).

Comment: @Tejas AFAIK there is no way to cancel closure when it is already added to a dispatch queue. Thats just how GCD works. If you really need it, consider scheduling a Timer or NSOperation

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the answer and quick response as well! :)